# Starting JQuery Mobile on PhoneGap with Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I know this may be a basic question but I cannot find a basic answer online.  How do I implement JQuery Mobile on my PhoneGap app that I am developing with android?  I am not clear which version I need to download and what notation I need to put in my Eclipse project and index.html file to have it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project creation wizard in the AppLaud Eclipse Plugin for PhoneGap Android has a check box to include jQuery Mobile into a project. Basically it adds the jQuery and jQuery Mobile files to the project and adds links from the index.html to them.

You can add the plugin to your Eclipse ADT by doing Install New Software -> Add https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download

More information at http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/

Comment: Okay I am almost there but when I import the JQuery Mobile Libraries using the function in the AppLaud setup but it just comes out jumbled together and gets an error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: http://applaudcloud.com also has a JQM/phonegap starter template. Oh and there phonegap examples are way better then the official documents. They actually work lol.

Comment: @clifgray Can you be more specific about what is jumbled? What happens if you follow http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt0 step by step?

Comment: @codaniel Yep. applaudcloud.com has a similar project creation to the AppLaud Eclipse plugin - just with fewer steps and without needing to set up Eclipse. (Note, I developed both of them.)

Comment: I have installed the plugin successfully and created new project using the same. But the javascript validator reports error as "case default is already defined" please help thanks in advance